# what happens when you type git init?

Tags: git, github, terminal, repository

I'm new to programming and I'm having trouble understanding `git init` command. For example, when I type `git init` on my terminal I get a return like this:

> Initialized empty Git repository in /Users/JohnDoe/Documents/.git/

What is this exactly? Am I creating a new folder for git projects? Am I doing nothing? Or am I turning my entire Documents directory into a repository?

Comment: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-init#_description

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/315911/git-for-beginners-the-definitive-practical-guide

Answer (score 1):

You created a local repository.   You can type `git status` and you should see '(home)' to verify you have a local repository.

One of the things to understand about git is that you can have a local repository and a remote repository. The next step would be to add files to your local repository. You can use the command `git add -all` to add all the files in your directory.

Answer (score 0):

## I hope this helps you git it.

Transform the current directory into a Git repository. This adds a .git subdirectory to the current directory and makes it possible to start recording revisions of the project.

https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/setting-up-a-repository/git-init